# How to do flatten in scala horizantally?

Tags: scala

I am trying  some basic logic using scala . I tried the below code but it throws error .

```
scala> val data = ("HI",List("HELLO","ARE"))
data: (String, List[String]) = (HI,List(HELLO, ARE))

 scala> data.flatmap( elem => elem)
  <console>:22: error: value flatmap is not a member of (String, List[String])
          data.flatmap( elem => elem)
```

Expected Output :

```
(HI,HELLO,ARE)
```

Could some one help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert this `Tuple2` into a `Tuple3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to `flatMap` on `Tuple2` which is not available in `current api`

If you don't want to change your input, you can `extract` the values from `Tuple2` and the extract the values for second tuple value as below

```
val data = ("HI",List("HELLO","ARE"))
val output = (data._1, data._2(0), data._2(1))
println(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for all answers. This answers fits my requirement

Comment: Pleased to help you. @SurenderRaja you can upvote too if it helped you ;)

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to flatMap over a tuple, which won't work. The following will work:

```
val data = List(List("HI"),List("HELLO","ARE"))

val a = data.flatMap(x => x)
```

Comment: Valid ;), +1, I like the easy way

Answer (score 2):

This will be very trivial in scala:

```
val data = ("HI",List("HELLO","ARE"))
println( data._1 :: data._2 )
```

what exact data structure are you working with?

If you are clear about you data structure:

```
type rec = (String, List[String])

val data : rec = ("HI",List("HELLO","ARE"))

val f = ( v: (String, List[String]) ) => v._1 :: v._2

f(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of observations:

1. Currently there is no `flatten` method for tuples (unless you use [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/flatten.scala)).
2. `flatMap` cannot be directly applied to a list of elements which are a mix of elements and collections.

In your case, you can make element "HI" part of a `List`:

```
val data = List(List("HI"), List("HELLO","ARE"))

data.flatMap(identity)
```

Or, you can define a function to handle your mixed element types accordingly:

```
val data = List("HI", List("HELLO","ARE"))

def flatten(l: List[Any]): List[Any] = l.flatMap{
  case x: List[_] => flatten(x)
  case x => List(x)
}

flatten(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If that's what you want:

```
val data = ("HI",List("HELLO,","ARE").mkString(""))
println(data)

>>(HI,HELLO,ARE)
```